# qBittorrent stuck zoomed out on monitor 2 only. Clearing ~/.config/qBittorrent and uninstall-reinstall doesn't help

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, zooming

I managed to zoom out with some weird gesture of the mouse and keyboard by accident. No matter what I do I can't figure out how to zoom back in with qBittorrent. It's unreadable as is.

Edit: It's also apparently only on my secondary monitor. Dragging it to the primary shows it zoomed as default. So confusing.

I've also now run `rm -r` on the ~/.config/qBittorent files in order to theoretically clear any settings, then uninstalled/reinstalled, so it must be Ubuntu causing the window to be zoomed out so far.

Comment: Please click [edit] and tell us a) which version number of Ubuntu you're using, and especially if you use a 'flavour' (i.e., Kubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Budgie, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, et al.) Also, b) what's your graphics adapter? c) Which graphics driver? d) Is resolution different between monitors? Please don't use Add Comment; use [edit] as that info belongs in the question.